# Received-SPF: neutral

Tags: email, email-server, spf

When I send emails from my application I am getting a spf neutral error.  I have been working with Google and my hosting company, but none of them can figure it out.  Below is my spf record.

```
"v=spf1 include:s920.tmd.cloud include:mx1.tmdhosting.com include:mx2.tmdhosting.com ip4:184.154.73.81 ip4:108.178.0.170 ip4:198.143.161.162 ip4: include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

Below is a snip of the email meta data.

```
    ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@holyfirepublishing.com header.s=default header.b=HRuHEiL6;
       spf=neutral (google.com: 108.178.0.170 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of publisher@holyfirepublishing.com) smtp.mailfrom=publisher@holyfirepublishing.com
Return-Path: <publisher@holyfirepublishing.com>
Received: from mx1.tmdhosting.com (mx1.tmdhosting.com. [108.178.0.170])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id b67-v6si3713737ioj.9.2018.04.28.17.31.24
        for <test@holyfirepublishing.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Sat, 28 Apr 2018 17:31:24 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 108.178.0.170 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of publisher@holyfirepublishing.com) client-ip=108.178.0.170;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@holyfirepublishing.com header.s=default header.b=HRuHEiL6;
       spf=neutral (google.com: 108.178.0.170 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of publisher@holyfirepublishing.com) smtp.mailfrom=publisher@holyfirepublishing.com
Received: from [184.154.73.81] (helo=s920.tmd.cloud) by mx1.tmdhosting.com with esmtps (TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256) (Exim 4.89) (envelope-from <publisher@holyfirepublishing.com>) id 1fCaFP-0005U5-6t for test@holyfirepublishing.com; Sat, 28 Apr 2018 19:31:24 -0500
```

I can really use some help building my spf record.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you including MX records?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `IN SPF "v=spf1 include:s920.tmd.cloud include:mx1.tmdhosting.com include:mx2.tmdhosting.com ip4:184.154.73.81 ip4:108.178.0.170 ip4:198.143.161.162 ip4: include:_spf.google.com ~all"` has several problems.

- Use `TXT` instead of `SPF` ([RFC 7208, 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-3.1)).
- In general, you should avoid multiple includes as there is a maximum amount of DNS queries per SPF check. For the same reason, direct `ip4` and `ip6` directives are always the best.
- Here, you have includes that doesn't contain SPF records. They should probably use `a` mechanism, instead. [Only "include" existing SPF records](http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/Common_mistakes#include).
- You should [list a server only once](http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/Common_mistakes#only-once), preferably using `ip4`. As `s920.tmd.cloud A 184.154.73.81`, `mx1.tmdhosting.com A 108.178.0.170` & `mx2.tmdhosting.com A 198.143.161.162`, the `a` mechanisms from the previous can be removed.
- The empty `ip4:` is a [syntax](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#ip4) error.
- While `+` for `Pass` is the default qualifier, I find it easier for beginners to use it to avoid confusion with the `exists`/`include` mechanisms and `redirect`/`exp` *modifiers* that doesn't have qualifiers.

We can assume you have the rest as you desire:

- The results suggests that at least the MX `108.178.0.170` is used for outgoing mail, so probably the three IP addresses are ok.
- The last `include` allows Gmail. Let's just assume you are using it for this domain.
- `~all` *soft fail* for rest. I agree that you shouldn't use *(hard) fail* before you have more experience with SPF and can be sure it won't cause any problems.

**Result:**

```
IN TXT "v=spf1 +ip4:184.154.73.81 +ip4:108.178.0.170 +ip4:198.143.161.162 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

Comment: that worked great.  Can you help me explain the dkim=temperror?  I think that is the last bit to get this working.

Comment: Interestingly I have seen bind9 produce this warning `found SPF/TXT record but no SPF/SPF record found, add matching type SPF record`, which from my reading of it goes directly against RFC 7208.

Comment: I created a new post for the dkim error.  If anyone has any knowledge on how to fix it, you can post it here. https://serverfault.com/questions/909909/email-dkim-temperror-no-key-for-signature

Comment: That's correct: another question on another error. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your domain doesn't actually have an SPF record. I don't know where you put it, but neither I nor Google can find it.

```
$ host -t txt holyfirepublishing.com
holyfirepublishing.com has no TXT record
```

Once you actually create an SPF record correctly, other mail servers should begin using it.

Comment: It's in an SPF rrtype.  Surprised googledomains lets you create them still.

Comment: @womble Yeah, that's strange, since nobody actually looks at that RR type anymore.

Comment: Also strange if Google and the hosting company can't point out all the obvious problems in the record.

Answer (score 2):

`Include` records must also be spf txt records.  If that is not your intent you can use `mx` if these are your MX records or `a:host.exanple.com` to permit the IPv4 address of `host.example.com`

Be mindful of the 10 DNS record limit. `mx` counts as one, regardless of the number of MX records.

These are all invalid:

include:s920.tmd.cloud include:mx1.tmdhosting.com include:mx2.tmdhosting.com

Comment: Actually `mx:tmdhosting.com` OR `a:mx1.tmdhosting.com`, not `mx` with the MX. As the `ip4` mechanism already covers all these addresses, these should be removed altogether.

Comment: I didn't look up what his MX records were, assuming they were the same. Seems like this "tmd hosting" should be doing email. :(