# Email dkim=temperror (no key for signature)

Tags: email, dkim

I have a custom built web application that sends emails.  This application is hosted by a third party.  This application sends emails through their servers.  I have correctly set my spf record.  However, when my application sends emails the emails are getting a dkim error.  I have no idea why I am getting this error.  Below you will find some of the meta data from an email sent from the web application.

```
Delivered-To: test@holyfirepublishing.com
Received: by 10.12.180.68 with SMTP id e4csp2649123qvf;
        Sun, 29 Apr 2018 07:12:41 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AB8JxZqDmZKGZ3MCbLlo7r0rfpdjBif9w8/vsXHKXx/+L+F5udEeQiZt97ERlXIYvazAodyXmjLk
X-Received: by 2002:a6b:98b:: with SMTP id 11-v6mr9699820ioj.90.1525011161636;
        Sun, 29 Apr 2018 07:12:41 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1525011161; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=K8ytU3THBqD8rUY0aBaOCbH2SVUlVeVEJJXoYt7Z53oQA3wdldhpYToHrqxOuDg8Jo
         lcQ1xqTYrh30FICoyOoRd+quDkQK5z//xlU1DXn753I+Tmc6aBBStMUMN7m3cGGWPW2j
         bTGBeAzFlx1PGYSE+aIzPLcdfXPl6vVpMtVfeKnHf6LrcK35D2wBbG9o88q1xTOCZ9Ue
         1fKI32QX7UgcT0zSrO4kLD9z1pS0jcYwS9wnbtAt5uVes+AyDjHR7YdSoUjT0SO5KVEc
         JFwIndndrLH5XznWwfHdUq7IrLnLech7FToqGPujqS/Pz0RxXDu96yzuwX54z+exrfjj
         JXWA==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=mime-version:to:from:subject:date:message-id:dkim-signature
         :arc-authentication-results;
        bh=uxadBWIDOxAaWOKJN8YSOnay3lDpPAaxgWm82T/s9FI=;
        b=qZ9xPSGu6SztmcnDRkioXDL3BZcyOhdxQjECf441oe/vaLCWzxHtEfBJlO4+zo8vBa
         /mij7vCitF2NFsh/yjCLxz/ellSuFfnDBc6ydOJ97t6X2y5eGVFREEDtTCigwi1exeQa
         4+nU/ls3wvXuiU1vJo96z5RjebxCDd7wkVLu6W/7EPA3C7PYRbTQbJi2egI8Hoc0KORw
         h7JaAwTfB787wdXnFuD72JT36LL52EjtSPUc4w7785VH49yH4rZhBeAFMU0JfAhoAu+3
         YJIO5XP2+rK0b/ksfy1U+DoFW81LW4+CmnG89CLYHddlDUGyz956RGUVoqI+VcHsZsYJ
         8sRw==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@holyfirepublishing.com header.s=default header.b=EXFzVKU0;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of publisher@holyfirepublishing.com designates 108.178.0.170 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=publisher@holyfirepublishing.com
Return-Path: <publisher@holyfirepublishing.com>
Received: from mx1.tmdhosting.com (mx1.tmdhosting.com. [108.178.0.170])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id m2-v6si4491466ioe.253.2018.04.29.07.12.41
        for <test@holyfirepublishing.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Sun, 29 Apr 2018 07:12:41 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of publisher@holyfirepublishing.com designates 108.178.0.170 as permitted sender) client-ip=108.178.0.170;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@holyfirepublishing.com header.s=default header.b=EXFzVKU0;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of publisher@holyfirepublishing.com designates 108.178.0.170 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=publisher@holyfirepublishing.com
Received: from [184.154.73.81] (helo=s920.tmd.cloud) by mx1.tmdhosting.com with esmtps (TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256) (Exim 4.89) (envelope-from <publisher@holyfirepublishing.com>) id 1fCn4C-0002gc-K4 for test@holyfirepublishing.com; Sun, 29 Apr 2018 09:12:41 -0500
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=holyfirepublishing.com; s=default; h=Content-Type:MIME-Version:To:From: Subject:Date:Message-ID:Sender:Reply-To:Cc:Content-Transfer-Encoding: Content-ID:Content-Description:Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender: Resent-To:Resent-Cc:Resent-Message-ID:In-Reply-To:References:List-Id: List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:List-Subscribe:List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive;
     bh=uxadBWIDOxAaWOKJN8YSOnay3lDpPAaxgWm82T/s9FI=; b=EXFzVKU0ZI0PBW6ug8u1mQ+D1 0WeVSF8lBoGNDKaM9o69wv9hkkedLn5Ga5hc6gaNGqjDtafv/DNv55Mo5t/a8Pqi48ciUBykHZl34 Hm98Zu4suFOK+MqMZIz9+Q7SZfgPdLRDtHLfyeLTRojxbeKSxJBZXTvvVT3N1Oy7PGQ0U1VR/WLe6 eTzli3cS7m6iI50CupM4cEPB0GY2eg1CRHAMk3lht4REa7WrsCeCJzDYqwCD8ojuo8ktQGbTtvKfB IsK+DBQT+W0c7GtICt1MvPp9UhLsb+bBvGAwWhzc8DARCW6N/I0EcOzqcV9Nujo3Y9Ch6eiDDeMYy qPPwf/elg==;
Received: from [184.154.73.81] (port=16188 helo=authors.holyfirepublishing.com) by s920.tmd.cloud with esmtpsa (TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128) (Exim 4.89_1) (envelope-from <publisher@holyfirepublishing.com>) id 1fCn4C-00ACo3-0A for test@holyfirepublishing.com; Sun, 29 Apr 2018 10:12:40 -0400
Message-ID: <bfb996586f80ae10b93c2f7de8665385@authors.holyfirepublishing.com>
Date: Sun, 29 Apr 2018 14:12:39 +0000
Subject: ed
From: Holy Fire Publishing <publisher@holyfirepublishing.com>
To: test@holyfirepublishing.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="_=_swift_v4_1525011159_6c682aef534d6916a1661ae64e35842a_=_"
X-Originating-IP: 184.154.73.81
X-SpamExperts-Domain: smtp-out.s920.tmd.cloud
X-SpamExperts-Username: 184.154.73.81
Authentication-Results: tmdhosting.com; auth=pass smtp.auth=184.154.73.81@smtp-out.s920.tmd.cloud
X-SpamExperts-Outgoing-Class: ham
X-SpamExperts-Outgoing-Evidence: Combined (0.11)
X-Recommended-Action: accept
X-Filter-ID: EX5BVjFpneJeBchSMxfU5ofMTyLsMxNNa79NOyRl4kR602E9L7XzfQH6nu9C/Fh9KJzpNe6xgvOx q3u0UDjvO1JtF3V00Djdp3UoOn/TrNhUFpOyEQHhn6Djm4dwHjyI6GJvfmVu97SEuqiv2A/Wxu/H 6thHOzZSgMLgT5nubXyfI3EVhqxj8Nu1voFLyLyTVa/Hj/lpqf8vwAdisrIBg4VkC48eQiO7bLwH uL7bs2gxLabuOOunQxV+pDIPQhL5PxO0jJAHsPdj1H6RNuBO69ryxNN7Nt2dqAnJR+rNdzv1wJNm k2OOvqxJC+I78JUyACQHwPTDFXEPVlYw9avkW9KDqQDBb2Jc1G66+z2HQZg45a4hT7CiYg8SCvI6 ZEK+MBH5YNWyvM39bJiwcDIpUHzSCH11x2j55k0vQWyIjNVOZQZ7JJKYXeLCzfLW9BSOGB+kK6X2 YkzEZOMV8NHwXLN7qYLAtCcaTgmnmyZDzqNSHDEoKrXCm1PS2vgB4ghQfb7mDHg6F7DCQw/QmRVt g675dwLB7orJf0UsoeQy3tTonV+E7OMXRvgtdyMlnmWiDV9lNYm5WzS+KSLj3jtoVhfBXB881d2n MQbnYGHCJ28tG8BTthNWTB1/5HxYxRg/56Dn5RwX9m/yl7fqKmGjdPo33lkt8ECA8ZsTjQzKO+Xo IZw0+8GnFDT9YVEr7iqcCTb71FzynTtMl1ZK50d7SmAkiNlF8yDvfn+8xtg2A5+mIE1y2+2rZk9T sAzY2/lJZuM7jUXIESohoO51xWmU8V2s3nPp1TdJicttLcyTSSrQ+yjGCjoKIAu+6onh8cJ0qjVl p0XhZmFVthT8ed1oWpaRgcwU9rlpCYIvaAUrUokSnhyEGzxc7gyYDzaDoEYweYhpXBAtxRdlRy6U 5bQe20FDmz24WKkPfOYR2dD7CCp/TsT9LCL4UdHDzEymj5r1llEjtKNMtF0f79BIT6ZN1Q==
X-Report-Abuse-To: spam@mx1.tmdhosting.com
```

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: How long is your DKIM key, 1024 or 2048 bit? 2048 bit keys are not recommended and unusable, since many DNS resolvers/servers are still unable to handle the query size needed for that. This is why 1024 bit keys are still the only ones which are recommended and production ready.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't have a DKIM record matching `d=holyfirepublishing.com; s=default;` ***d***omain / ***s***elector. That would be `default._domainkey.holyfirepublishing.com. TXT "v=DKIM1; p=yourPublicKey"`,  currently returning `NXDOMAIN`. The `dkim=temperror (no key for signature)` is consistent with this.

Comment: That was it.  I was confused because I had one set for my google stuff, but I did not have one set for my domain.

Comment: That's why there are *selectors*; to allow more than one service without need to share private keys.

Comment: Do the selector and the DNS entry prefix always need to match?

Comment: That's where the DKIM validator searches for the public key. [RFC 6376, 3.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6376#section-3.1)